# refresh position of dragged object after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I am using jqueryui drag and drop (to make captcha plugin) to drag image into one div container and after that i make a ajax call . is this possible that when i make the ajax call and it gets complete then the position of the dragged images be reset ?

my drag function is (part of code)

```
e("div.eL-captcha > div.eL-possibilities > img").draggable({
    opacity: .6,
    revert: "invalid",
    refreshPositions: true
});
```

and my ajax call is

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../../captcha/miclass.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: $('#frm_sample').serialize(),
    success: function(data) {

    if(data=="Captcha error!")
    {
    alert("WRONG CAPTCHA ! Please Complete the Captcha By Choosing the correct image or for audio entering the right value");       
    }
    else
    {
    $("form")[0].reset();
    $(".mi_comments_container").prepend(data);

        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course. Save the positions in an array or set it to the images as data attribute before making them draggable. Then use

```
$.each
```

To set their left and top css values to the original values you saved.